# Cell Fracture Issue | Cells appear werid

Tags: physics

I'm having an issue with cell fracture where no matter how many subdivides I do after clicking cell fracture this happens I can't find any helpful info online I have no modfiers set before cell fracture and my sub divisions are applied. Any help would be appreciated
Images
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bGFL.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qimmj.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ramv5.png) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiH49.png) [image]

Comment: Uncheck Random subdivision.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth I'm not able to see this option unsure if i'm looking in the wrong place or blind. Is this a checkbox on the cell fracture options or elsewhere? Thanks for your help

Comment: No, this checkbox has to do with subdivision tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too just right now and apparently scaling the object up before the cell fracture to a comically large size worked for me.[image: small vase with a broken cell fracture]

[image: fixed cell fracture after scaling]