# Uncheck Random subdivision | Cell Fracture

Tags: physics

I asked a question on how to fix an issue and recieved a comment saying to Uncheck Random Subdivison but I was unable to find this option and the user who commented has not responded where would I find this option this is in the context of cell fracture, thank you

Below is the link to my previous question for more details

[Cell Fracture Issue | Cells appear werid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194506/cell-fracture-issue-cells-appear-werid?noredirect=1#comment326022_194506)

Comment: "I asked about an issue" is not particularly descriptive and without knowing more about the issue, it's all second-guessing. So... why don't you post a link to the original question? You can do so by clicking on the edit link below your question.

Comment: @metaphor_set thank you I have done so, was unaware this was allowed as other fourms I have used in the past remove links to previous questions claiming them to be a waste and that issues should remain to one post. Thank you for your help